# SlideDown only after SlideUp ended

Tags: jquery, html

I have this following code.
I am trying to SlideDown div2 but only after div1 has ended to SlideUp, how can I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>slideDown()</h1>
        <input type="button" id="btn" value="slideDown">
        <div id="d1" style="background:red;width:100px;height:100px">This is the Div</div>
        <div id="d2" style="background:blue;width:100px;height:100px;display:none">This is the Div</div> 
        <script src="js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function ()
            {
                $("#btn").click(function ()
                {
                    $("#d1").slideUp(2000);
                    $("#d2").hide();                         
                    // do it only after slideup has ended                          
                    $("#d1").hide();
                    $("#d2").slideDown(2000);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your script tag to

```
     <script>
  $(document).ready(function()
 {

       $("#btn").click(function()
       {
         $("#d1").slideUp(2000,function(){
                $("#d1").hide();
                $("#d2").slideDown(2000);
         });                    
         });

    });
   </script>
```

for more reference on slideUp & slideDown event refer  [this](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/)

Answer (score 4):

You can callback the slideUp.

```
 $("#d1").slideUp(2000, function(){ $("#d2").slideDown(2000); });
```

Here a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qodg8ssh/)